# AWS Athena display incorrect decimal value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, informatica

Source csv file has this column value = 1

We use Informatica to load this file as parquet file into AWS S3 and make this output column as decimal(38,10)

The value shown in the parquet file as 1.00

We created an HIVE external table for this parquet file in Athena, and the value is shown as 0.0000000100

If we connect to beeline and query this hive table, the value is shown as 1.0000000000 which is what we want.

Not sure why Athena is not displaying this decimal value as defined.

Comment: is it happening to only that column or all other decimal columns? can you dump the data into a txt file and see how its coming up. also are you sure the file structure, sequence you have in parquet is matching to the hive table?